# Performing local security checks with OpenVAS 5 from Backtrack 5 r3

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, security, backtrack

I'm trying to perform local security checks using OpenVAS on a remote machine, from my Backtrack5r3 machine. I have followed the official OpenVAS guide [Howto: Perform local security checks](http://www.openvas.org/performing_lsc.html) and I have checked that connecting via SSH both with and without a password to the remote machine from my Backtrack machine works. However, when I start a Task in OpenVAS and monitor the network traffic using Wireshark, I see that there is absolutely NO packet captured, which uses the SSH protocol. I mean that OpenVAS does not even attempt to connect to the remote machine via SSH.

The OpenVAS report is empty which leads me to believe there are some missing dependencies and/or configuration issues. However, I was expecting Backtrack to be able to do OpenVAS local security checks out-of-the-box.

**Note** that if I run a "Full and fast" scan on the same machine the OpenVAS report does contain threats and logs, which are normal for a remote scan. However, I want to perform a local security check which requires my machine to log-into the remote machine via SSH.

Does anyone have an idea about how I can fix this problem? There isn't too much out there on OpenVAS local security checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backtrack5 r3 does not have the latest versions of Greenbone Security Desktop/Assistant. Therefore the "Credentials" NVT family is still visible. However, if you download the latest version of GSD (> 1.2.1) or use the successor of Backtrack5, Kali Linux, then you will see that the "Credentials" NVT family is no longer visible from the GUI, hence you can no longer follow the official OpenVAS guide [Howto: Perform local security checks](http://www.openvas.org/performing_lsc.html), because you have no where to upload the public/private SSH keys to.

Therefore, to perform local security checks via SSH you have to:

- Create a new Credential (Name, Login and Password) via the "Credentials" tab which is in the Navigator menu for GSA and in View>Credentials for GSD
- Create a new Target and select the Name of the previously created credential from the drop-down list corresponding to "SSH Credential (optional)" field.
- Create a new Task where you select the previously created Target and a Scan Config which includes the local security checks for the platform(s) you wish to scan.